# Check if .NET webbrowser control can play flash

Tags: .net, flash, browser

how can i check from code if webbrowser control can play flash or it showing broken image, after flash page is loaded?

Idea is that if user can't play flash, application should open Internet explorer with adobe flash player website, so user can install flash in IE, and enable flash content.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since Flash in IE is an Active-X control, you can use C# from the application itself to see if you can instantiate a a COM object with Flash's Class ID:

```
private bool IsFlashInstalled()
{
    object instance = null;
    try
    {
        var type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"));
        instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(instance);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to cache the result as much as possible.

Comment: Can we play RTMP feed based on this instance?

Answer (score 0):

For all of your flash related needs, I would recommend using the [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) JavaScript library.

Tutorial: ["Detecting Flash Player versions and embedding SWF files with SWFObject 2"](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html)